# How can i count element who are equal a value ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i count element in a ng-repeat who are equal a variable

for example i do have this ng-repeat and i want to count every elements who Fund.status are equals "Finish"or "Todo":

```
<tbody ng-repeat="Fund in ListTask| filter:TreeFilter |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
                        <tr ng-dblclick="open(Fund.id,Fund)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{Fund.type}}">
                            <td>{{Fund.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Beneficiary}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Title}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.category}}</td>
                            <td>{{FormField.shortDate(Fund.CreationDate)}}</td>
                            <td>{{FormField.shortDate(Fund.DueDate)}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Team}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Officer}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it is a bad practice. Counting stuff in your view during an ng-repeat is nasty. You are far better off doing the counting in your controller and exposing the result to the view, like that

```
$scope.thoseThatEqualFundOrTodo = function(items){
  return _.find(items, function(item){
     item.status === 'Todo' || item.status === 'Fund';
  }).length;
});
```

Then in your template you can do like:

```
<table data-scope-attribute="filteredTasks" data-scope-attribute-watch="ListTask| filter:TreeFilter |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">

Result:  {{thoseThatEqualFundOrTodo(filteredTasks)}}

<tbody ng-repeat="Fund in filteredTasks">
                        <tr ng-dblclick="open(Fund.id,Fund)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{Fund.type}}">
                            <td>{{Fund.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Beneficiary}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Title}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.category}}</td>
                            <td>{{FormField.shortDate(Fund.CreationDate)}}</td>
                            <td>{{FormField.shortDate(Fund.DueDate)}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Team}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Officer}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried this too but i didn't work i do have an error because it doesn't know  _.find it say that [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:

Comment: Of course it can't, I am using http://lodash.com/ to do the filtering. You should do your filtering on your own by just looping the items...